# Laravel about Requests

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i am new in programing laravel. so here I will not ask about my problems but I am here just want to ask how to use laravel. here I would like to ask how to use:

Determining If an Input Value Is Present in laravel. and what it does?

thanks ^^

Comment: Why don't you go and checkout https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch .. The series is completely free to watch..

Comment: Yes, I also prefer http://laracast.com. This is official site.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel is really a good MVC Framework. 
I can suggest you some source from where you can get better understanding of Laravel Framework.

1. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2
2. https://laracasts.com/skills/laravel

For simple example - How to use Laravel after installation

- Go to path using terminal ex. /var/www/laravel/project
- Go to - /var/www/laravel/project/resources/views
- Create a directory test and create a file index.php
- Create a controller - `php artisan make:controller TestController`
- Create a function `testGet()` and return view - `return view('test.index');` //test is directory and index is file
- Create a function `testPost(Request $request)` and to get data use `$data = $request->all();` and then print this data.
- Create a model with migration file - `php artisan make:model Test --migration`
- Go to route file - /var/www/laravel/project/app/Http/routes.php
- Add line `Route::get('/test', 'TestController@testGet');`
- Add line `Route::post('/test', 'TestController@testPost');`

Now check GET request to your project http://project/test it will call testGet function.
POST request http://project/test?name=Adam will call testPost function and will print your name.

Comment: Is this answer helpful for you ?

Answer (score 0):

as said in the comments you better check laracasts! its the laravel school
anyway to anwser your question, its simple

**View**

```
<input type="text" name="fname">
```

**Controller**

```
public function doingstuff (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    if ($request->has('fname')) {
        // a man gotta do what a man gotta do here
    }
 }
```

smooth huh? :3