# Understanding MVC on PHP with real application implementation

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Recently I have tried to read about MVC and OOP a lot. But every tutorial I found only used for displaying some static information on screen and steps without proper explanation what the code do. I have difficulty in finding a good tutorial with real application implementation such as to-do list or simple application with database.

I would appreciate if someone could explain to me how to build an application with database with MVC and PHP.

Thanks

EDIT: And I would like to know is there any way to create a working app without using framework

Comment: You can start with Laravel MVC Framework. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36764181/laravel-about-requests/36766104#36766104
There i have mentioned official tutorial site url.

Comment: @Bhaskar Rajoriya Is there any way to build an app using MVC without using framework?

Comment: If you want to create your own framework or just want to develop app with following oops and MVC concepts then you can read about the concept of MVC. I can share links to know more about MVC if you want.

Comment: @Bhaskar Rajoriya Yes please. I could use some link

Comment: Please read 
1 http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html
You can also download source from http://www.phpro.org/downloads/mvc-0.0.4.tar.gz
2 http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/ read and get download link from that page.

Please let me know if this is helpful and enough to create our own small MVC Framework.

Comment: @BhaskarRajoriya Thanks.. That link helped soo much.. Can you post as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I have posted my Answer. Please let me know if any editing is required.

Comment: @BhaskarRajoriya cool.. thanks for your help

Comment: your Most Welcome. @Agus Zendy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create your own framework or just want to develop app with following oops and MVC concepts then you have to read about the concept of MVC.
Please read

1. http://phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html - You can also
   download source from http://phpro.org/downloads/mvc-0.0.4.tar.gz
2. http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php read and get
   download link from that page.

Please let me know if this is helpful and enough to create our own small MVC Framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see a real world application with MVC pattern in PHP , you should check Opencart like open source projects. If you want to know how the things are going in MVC projects, i can summarize it as :

Request goes to "Bootstrap" file of Framework than it calls "Router" to invoke methods inside controllers. These methods basically do fetch data from "Model" , processes this data and gives it to "View". By the way in nowadays world "Router" don't force you to invoke a method. You can bind a function to "Route" like Laravel does.

Comment: What i mean is there any way building an working app without using framework.

Comment: You can develop your own MVC Project with only "Controller","Model","View","Router" components. If you are talking about can i do all of them in one page like other coding techniques, no you can't.

Comment: KESKIN Could you guide to tutorial or some kind of reference for learning those?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to learn it through frameworks, I would recommend at least learn how to use [Compposer](http://getcomposer.org/). Find separate packages for every part of MVC and try to glue them together to make a website.

You basically need the following parts:

- A database component, I would recommend a tiny ORM here (the M)
- A router component (the C)
- A templating engine (the V)

I write router instead of controller, because controllers can be simple callbacks, and a router component should support them.

I suggest going for a tiny project, like a small blog. You will need more component as you develop, like authentication or authorization part for blog admin. Search for the right component, and glue them together.

Also, to learn more and more, read components source code to learn how they work. It is better than writing your own version, because they have solved problems you don't even know yet.